# Apple PackageMaker CLI: Is there any way to include Postinstall Actions?

Tags: macos, installation, command-line-interface, packagemaker, mpkg

I have a PackageMaker .pmdoc designed in the PackageMaker GUI. The top level package item on the sidebar (above the contents) has two Postinstall Actions. They're "Open File" actions.

When I build the package inside the PackageMaker GUI, the resulting .mpkg includes:
`Contents/Packages/packagenamePostflight.pkg`

But when I build the package with the **CLI**, the Postflight.pkg is **missing**.

I built with the CLI using the command:
`/Developer/usr/bin/packagemaker --doc package.pmdoc/ --out package.mpkg`

At the top of the output, it tells me:
`packagemaker[55900:903] Warning: unknown or deprecated action`
`packagemaker[55900:903] Warning: unknown or deprecated action`

Google tells me others have encountered this problem in the past, without finding a solution:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/Installer-dev/2010/Jan/msg00003.html

Anyone have any ideas besides not using PackageMaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider abandoning PackageMaker.  I just switched to Iceberg and although it has its own quirks, I found it smarter when it dealt with post installation tasks.